# ODBC connection error:No such command "odbc show" ODBC connection fail in asterisk*CLI

Tags: mysql, linux, odbc, voip, asterisk

Problems:  I am using AsteriskNow which running asterisk 2.0 server in VirtualBox. And i want to connect Asterisk with MySQL databases using ODBC modules. But it fails. When i started with asterisk*CLI> odbc show     The command prompt shows that "No such command ODBC SHOW"

My Objectives: configure ODBC in asterisk to access MySQL from Asterisk's dialplan directly and dynamically.

What i did: I installed my AsteriskNow in VirtualBox. The version of asterisk is 2.0, the CentOS version 5.8 final. I firstly installed related Linux RPMs by

```
yum -y install unixODBC-devel
yum -y install libdbi-dbd-mysql
yum -y install mysql-connector-odbc
```

My detail configured files are as follows:

/etc/odbc.ini

```
[asterisk-connector]
Description           = MySQL connection to 'asterisk' database
Driver                = MySQL
Database              = asterisk
Server                = localhost
UserName              = root        
Password              = mypassword
Port                  = 3306
Socket                = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
```

/etc/odbcinst.ini

```
# Driver from the mysql-connector-odbc package
# Setup from the unixODBC-libs package
[MySQL]
Description = ODBC for MySQL
Driver      = /usr/lib/libmyodbc3_r.so
Setup       = /usr/lib/libodbcmyS.so
;Driver64   = /usr/lib64/libmyodbc3_r.so
;Setup64        = /usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
FileUsage   = 1
```

/etc/asterisk/res_odbc.conf

```
[asterisk]
enabled=>yes
dsn=>asterisk-connector
;dsn=>asterisk
username=>root
password=>mypassword
pooling=>no
limit=>0
pre-connect=>yes
```

When i used "isql" command to connect MySQL databases, it works fine
[image]

But when i started the console in CLI, input command ***odbc show*** . it shows ***No SUCH COMMAND "odbc show "***

[image]

And i am confusing here, and do not know how to solve it. I googled it and find someone recommend to solve it by  having the res_odbc.so module loaded. Thus i went through the file modules.conf and add those modification into files

```
autoload=yes
preload => res_odbc.so
preload => res_config_odbc.so
```

After being modified, the complete file is as follow"
/etc/asterisk/modules

```
;
; Asterisk Module Loader configuration file
;
;

[modules]
autoload=yes
;
; Any modules that need to be loaded before the Asterisk core has been
; initialized (just after the logger has been initialized) can be loaded
; using 'preload'. This will frequently be needed if you wish to map all
; module configuration files into Realtime storage, since the Realtime
; driver will need to be loaded before the modules using those configuration
; files are initialized.
;
; An example of loading ODBC support would be:
preload => res_odbc.so
preload => res_config_odbc.so
;
; As FreePBX is using Local as the channel for queue members we need to make sure
; that pbx_config.so and chan_local.so are preloaded. If not, queue members
; will be marked as invalid until app_queue is reloaded. 
preload => pbx_config.so
preload => chan_local.so
;
; Uncomment the following if you wish to use the Speech Recognition API
;preload => res_speech.so
;
; If you want, load the GTK console right away.  
; KDE console is obsolete and was removed from Asterisk 2008-01-10
;
noload => pbx_gtkconsole.so
;load => pbx_gtkconsole.so
noload => pbx_kdeconsole.so
;
; Intercom application is obsoleted by
; chan_oss.  Don't load it.
;
noload => app_intercom.so
;
; DON'T load the chan_modem.so, as they are obsolete in * 1.2

noload => chan_modem.so
noload => chan_modem_aopen.so
noload => chan_modem_bestdata.so
noload => chan_modem_i4l.so

; Trunkisavail is a broken module supplied by Trixbox
noload => app_trunkisavail.so

; Ensure that format_* modules are loaded before res_musiconhold
;load => format_ogg_vorbis.so
load => format_wav.so
load => format_pcm.so

; format_au.so is removed from Asterisk 1.4 and later, remove ; to enable
;load => format_au.so

; This isn't part of 'Asterisk' iteslf, it's part of asterisk-addons. If this isn't
; installed, asterisk will fail to start. But it does need to go here for native MOH
; to work using mp3's. 
;   Note that on a system with a high number of calls, using a compressed audio format for
;   musiconhold takes CPU resources. Converting these files to ulaw/alaw makes the job
;   much easier for your CPU.
load => format_mp3.so
load => res_musiconhold.so
;
; Load either OSS or ALSA, not both
; By default, load no console driver
;
noload => chan_alsa.so
noload => chan_oss.so
;
noload => app_directory_odbcstorage.so 
noload => app_voicemail_odbcstorage.so
```

After did this, i went back the CLI console to reload the res_odbc.so. But it failed to find the res_odbc.so 
[image]

I need someone give me hints on solving the ODBC connections problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the AsteriskNOW environment, to get `res_odbc.so`, which is the module that provides the ODBC resource to Asterisk, you need to have the `asterisk-odbc` package installed.

(Depending on how your AsteriskNOW installation is configured with respect to the packages.asterisk.org repositories, you may need `asterisk18-odbc` or a similar versioned package instead.)

If you have `res_odbc.so` (check in `/usr/lib/asterisk/modules` for this file) and it is still not loading correctly, you should check the Asterisk logs in `/var/log/asterisk` for messages relating to `res_odbc` for more information.

Comment: Hi, zigg. I cant express how much thanks to you because of you kindly and helpful hints! After "sudo yum install asterisk-odbc" i think i can "module load res_odbc.so" and it can execute "odbc show" within asterisk*CLI. If you do not mind, could you please leave your email. I probably want to ask sth about asterisk with Mysql.  My email is: ylai728@gmail.com    Anyways, Thanks a lot. I had stucked on this problem for over 3 weeks...

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, accept, and vote of confidence; but I think you may want to look elsewhere for help actually getting ODBC or MySQL working.  I haven't actually done that myself; I'm just familiar with the way AsteriskNOW is structured.

Answer (score 3):

Try do follwoing:

```
asterisk -rvvv
module unload res_odbc.so
module load res_odbc.so
```

And see output.

Comment: No. it fails to unload and load the module. The output is "unable to unload resource res_odbc.so" 'Command unload res_odbc.so' failed.

Comment: yes,that is ok becuase it not loaded. what exactaly show "load"?

Comment: when i exectued "module load res_odbc.so". it shows: unable to unload resource res_odbc.so" 'Command unload res_odbc.so

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you use the isql command you receive an error (Unknown attribute UserName).

Try with this /etc/odbc.ini file:

```
[asterisk-connector]
Description = MySQL connection to 'asterisk' database
Driver      = MySQL
DATABASE    = asterisk
SERVER      = localhost
USER        = root
PASSWORD    = mypassword
PORT        = 3306
Option      = 3
```

I dont known if is valid for CentOS but in Debian I had to recompile Asterisk and execute menuselect in order to work. To do that, go to your Asterisk fonts directory:

```
$ ./configure

$ make clean

$ make menuselect
```

Please verify that the following modules are checked:

[*] cdr_odbc

[*] cdr_adaptive_odbc

[*] func_odbc

[*] func_realtime

[*] pbx_realtime

[*] res_config_odbc

[*] res_odbc

and then:

```
$ sudo make install
```

I hope that help you.

Comment: When i execute Command ./configure   it returns -bash:-./configure No such file or directory.  Do i need to use this command in any specific directory?

Comment: you need use that in asterisk source directory. Before that you have download and untar source.

Comment: I am confusing that i do not know the asterisk source directory.Is it the directory that having the asterisk installation source file ? Because i installed asteriskNow, and do not need to compile asterisk in centOS. What should i do next step?

Comment: Thanks guys! I think i found the problems.:)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forget to add some important module when you do "make menuselect" check it.

Besides and it is very important you must establish  "limit=>1" in the configuration file that you describe (/etc/asterisk/res_odbc.conf) if your are using mysql as relational database o just comment the line. If you are following the orreilly guide (http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449332426/asterisk-DB.html) you can see the errata (http://oreilly.com/catalog/errata.csp?isbn=9780596517342).

Answer (score 0):

Do

```
sudo service asterisk restart
```

Works like a charm