# How to recompile asterisk in CentOS 5.8?

Tags: linux, centos, asterisk, pbx

I already installed asteriskNow 2.0 ISO, thus after system installation, i've already have built-in asterisk within CentOS. I do not need to download source package and compile the source files. But right now, i have an situation that requires to recompile asterisk again.

I checked it out the installation tutorial which needs to go to the asterisk source directory to execute following commands:

```
# make clean
# ./configure
# make menuselect
# make install
# make samples
```

My questions :  Is it the asterisk source directory means the directory which has asterisk installation files? But in my case, i do not download and compile the asterisk source ever.What should i do?

Comment: I think it's worth asking why you say you need to recompile.  Also do know that you won't be able to recompile without source code, so you will need to get that first.

Comment: I want to install ODBC in order to let dialplan can directly access the Database(My problem is here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681048/odbc-connection-errorno-such-command-odbc-show-odbc-connection-fail-in-asteri). But some modules is not loaded, so i think i need to update the source package and re-compile the asterisk.

Comment: I responded there, as I do not believe you need to recompile Asterisk under AsteriskNOW for ODBC support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked myself: It needs to download source from and execute the following commands:

```
wget http://downloads.asterisk.org/pub/telephony/asterisk/asterisk-1.8.17.0.tar.gz
tar xzf asterisk-1.8.17.0.tar.gz
cd asterisk-1.8.17.0
./configure
make
make install
```